# Set many CheckBox

Tags: c#, checkbox

I need simple logic iteration but many item...
this is my code

```
        byte[] nc1 = new byte[40];
        nc1 = ChekSt(36, "192.168.2.55", 38, 40);

        //I need to iterate 40 times so my 40 checkbox can be updated

        switch (nc1[0])
        {
            case 1: checkBox1.Checked = false; break;
            case 2: checkBox1.Checked = true; checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate; break;
            case 3: checkBox1.Checked = true; checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked; break;
        }
```

i have checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3... to checkBox40

i need someting like `checkBox(i).checked = true;`

so don't have to write my code 40 times

anyone have idea...?

Comment: Wow, what user manipulation causes you to update 40 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in yourPanelContainer.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
   checkbox.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: should be .Controls instead of .Children

Answer (score 1):

Put the check boxes in an array or a List so that you can manipulate them in a set-based manner.

For example

```
var list = new List<CheckBox>();
list.Add(checkBox1);
list.Add(checkBox2);
list.Add(checkBox3);

list[2].Checked = true;
```